# What is transil and how it works?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, transient, transient-suppression

[image]

Can anyone tell me how transil works and what its purpose is, because I can't find information?
Thank you!

What is the purpose of Z1 and Z2 and when they work? Input voltage is 230V AC
and the transil breakdown voltage is 15V.

Comment: What does the application note tell you?

Comment: Weird name, sounds more like a drug than a diode

Comment: That **photo** of a screen with totally uneven lighting is really an insult. As someone who's able to ask here, we *must* expect you to at least put in as much effort as using your operating system's "screenshot" functionality.

Comment: You've signed up to SE just for doing this question. Could you ever have tried "what is transil" in google? The search returned a lot of useful links.

Answer (score 5):

Transil is a trademark from ST for its TVS diodes. TVS diodes behave somewhat like zener diodes: the current flows through them as soon as the voltage exceeds a given value. Contrary to Zener diodes, they are designed to get a huge power (600W and 1500W are standard power ratings) but only for a very short period of time. Moreover, they are generally designed to fail in short-circuit.

Comment: Transil also uses Avalanche effect with negative resistance incremental and lower VI loss for a lightning transient rating of 8kV vs MOV’s http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/30/f6/d4/72/7d/74/45/bc/CD00003857.pdf/files/CD00003857.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003857.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Z1 and Z2 are used to stabilize the amplitude value of the AC voltage on T1.
 Z2 limits the value of the positive half-period and Z1 negative half-period.

At the output of T1 the shape of the signal will be reminiscent of rectangular pulses (limited sinusoid). The amplitude of which will weakly depend on the amplitude of the signal of the AC line.

The phase shift between AC line and output T1 is constant. This can be used to synchronize something with the AC line.